# Unable to fetch date from UIDatePicker which is used inside of UIActionSheet which opens on TextField click

Tags: ios, datepicker, uiactionsheet

My Method where the acton sheet is called

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [txtSourceTime resignFirstResponder];

    UIActionSheet *sheet1 = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Source time" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];
    [sheet1 setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleDefault];
    [sheet1 setTag:3];
    [sheet1 showInView:self.view];

    time = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    time.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
    time.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

    [time setBounds:CGRectMake(0, -125, 320, 200)];
    [sheet1 addSubview:time];
    [sheet1 showFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 300, 320, 300) inView:self.view animated:YES];
    [sheet1 setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 500)];
}
```

Unable to get the date in the textbox when i click done in actionsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add an `UIActionSheetDelegate` method to know when the Done button is tapped and then update the `UITextField` with the date from the `UIDatePicker`. E.g.:

In the .h:

Add the `UIActionSheetDelegate` protocol:

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>
    // ...
@end
```

In the .m:

Add `UIActionSheet` delegate method to know when action sheet is being dismissed (i.e., one of the buttons is tapped):

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    // buttonIndex of 1 is the Done button
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        NSDate *date = time.date;

        // Date shows in text field, but is not nicely formatted
        textField.text = date.description;
    }
}
```

and set the delegate for the `UIActionSheet`:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //...

    UIActionSheet *sheet1 = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Source time" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];
    sheet1.delegate = self;

    //...
}
```

Do note that per Apple's documentation, this is not the recommended use of an `UIActionSheet`:

> UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add
>   views to its hierarchy.

Another alternative is to add the `UIDatePicker` as the `inputView` on the `UITextField`. For the Cancel and Done buttons, add an `inputAccessoryView` on the `UITextField` (which would show at the top of the `UIDatePicker`.

Comment: It worked fine in my case but it gives me Date and time of format [dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss TZD] where as i want only [hh:mm] and that to of local Timezone taht is, IST

Comment: Use a `NSDateFormatter` to get the format you want - the answer from @ssmanohar includes an example. Just change the `setDateFormat` to `@"HH:MM"`. If you only want the `UIDatePicker` to show time, set `datePickerMode` to `UIDatePickerModeTime`, e.g., `time.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code.....

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        printf("\n cancel");

    }else{
      printf("\n Done");
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
        NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:time.date];
        _txtSourceTime.text = strDate;

    }
}
```